# Reset Redux store after each test with jest

Tags: testing, redux, jestjs, specifications

I am using Jest to test my Redux actions, sometimes it happens that a test does something which conflicts with what other tests do.
For example, I test an action called **add a user** so it increases the length of the store to 1, then I test another action called **add and delete a user**, it expects the store to be empty after the process but the store still has a user that was existed since the first test.

Is there an accepted way to reset the Redux store for a fresh start after each test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My recommendation would be to create a new Redux store for each test - not reset it.
That way, your middlewares etc. also start with a clean state.

You could use something like the [setupApiStore](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/master/packages/toolkit/src/query/tests/helpers.tsx#L169) helper in the Redux Toolkit Tests.

A simplified version would look like

```js
function setupTestStore() {
  const refObj = {}
  
  beforeEach(() => {
    const store = configureStore({ reducer })
    refObj.store = store
    refObj.Wrapper = function Wrapper({ children }: any) {
      return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>
    }
  })

  return refObj
}
```

and in your tests

```js
const storeRef = setupTestStore()

it('tests something', () => {
  render(<MyComponent />, { wrapper: storeRef.wrapper }
}


it('tests something with another store', () => {
  render(<MyComponent2 />, { wrapper: storeRef.wrapper }
}
```